# VBA obtain a variable value from an userform

Tags: vba

I'm trying to obtain the value for `Teller` from an userform in my module. Here's my userform code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Teller As Long
Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox

Teller = 1
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet").Range("S1").Value Then
        Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & Teller)
        chkBox.Caption = Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(i, 9).Value
        chkBox.Left = 5
        chkBox.Top = 25 + ((Teller - 1) * 20)
        Teller = Teller + 1
    End If
Next i    
End Sub
```

And my module code:

```
Dim p As Long
Dim x As String
With UserForm
    .Show
    For p = 1 To .Teller
        x= .Controls("CheckBox_" & p).Caption
        MsgBox (x)
    Next p
    End
End With
```

`UserForm.Teller` won't give me the value of `Teller`. How do I get this?

Comment: `teller` is declared as private to the userform, so modules will not be able to read it. You can declare teller as public in a module, which will give you the ability to read it from other modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teller isn't an object or method of the userform, it's a variable you have defined in the userform_initialize module.

What you could do is declare the variable as a public variable in your module and then call it in your userform. You do this by declaring the variable above your subroutine in the module as public as below.

```
Public Teller As Long
```

Then you would just use

```
For p = 1 to teller
```

in your module

You would need to reset the variable to 0 manually at the end of the code/ when the userform is closed if you want it to reset on each run

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it seems like the value of `Teller` is empty in the module, since it gives me no output.

Comment: When I put a `MsgBox(Teller)` at the end of the `With Userform` it shows a blanco messagebox. Not even a 0 or 1, just nothing.

Comment: Try and declare it at the top of the module rather than in the userform, it should work then. My mistake! But make sure to remove it from the Userform Module first

Comment: No problem, happy to help Stan!

Comment: @user8234201 you should edit and fix your answer so it is accurate.  (Maybe show it as public in Stan's module code)